# how to handle clicked links in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

i have blackberry two examples for displaying html contents 
1 - for blackberry 5.00 using BrowserField 
2 - for blackberry 4.6  using RenderingApplication and HTTPConection

i need to know who to handle clicked links in each one ?

and if there is another way to display html content in blackberry 4.6

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reade this may be helpful to you..
it includes difference between browser field and render application.
Click [link] : 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/net-rim-device-api-browser-field2/m-p/416465